# Getting only Values from ModelForm

Tags: python, django

How can i get only field values? I have simple values a,b,c,d in var Lotnisko. Now i wanna create form with this vaules but Django generate me only HTML output like this:

```
<option>a</option>
<option>b</option>
```

but i only wanna simple vars and later create some like this in template:

```
{% for a in form.od %}
 {{ a.value }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Yup i know my language skills is very bad ;)

Models.py

```
class BusZLok(models.Model):
    Lotnisko = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Lotnisko
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Lotnisko Odlotu"
        verbose_name_plural = "Lotniska Odlotu"

class Kursy(models.Model):
    trasa = models.CharField('Nazwa Trasy',max_length=30)
    od = models.ForeignKey(BusZLok)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.trasa
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Trasa"
        verbose_name_plural = "Trasy"

class RezerwacjaFormOne(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Kursy
        fields = ['od']
```

Comment: It is kind of hard to do that since it is default behavior of Django deal with Foreign key field. My question is that why you don't dropdown list for display foreign key. I mean what is the benefit for you to set all the foreign keys as plain text.

Comment: I wanna dropdown list but my list, not django auto generated (site template was made in adobe muse :< ). Now I use one dirty hack:
In views.py i wrote "lotniska = BusZLok.objects.all()" and this works :)

Comment: well, not quite sure what lotniska is, but as long as it works, it should be fine. I just wanna say that be careful about displaying dropdown list or whatever list to show the foreign key. For now, you may think it is acceptable, but it is because you don't have enough data to slow down your site. And the way you do it 'objects.all()' is similar to how Django do it. Quick tip, since usually you don't need all the attribute of instance of foreign key. you can do "objects.values_list('id', 'lotnisko')". it will just pull the value  rather than the whole instance. it will accelerate your site.